# Transparent material overlapped error when i export GLTF

Tags: rendering, node-editor, transparency, glass, gltf

I'm trying to export transparent materials in GLTF for AR.

but i found some issue when transparent materials overlapped in view, the texture looks like it breaks. I guess it's from the alpha map. It can't separate front and back.
[image]

however this GLTF file coverted in USDZ and open it up in IOS AR, it works well.
[image]

i searched BSDF settings for transparent materials in GLTF and followed it but how can i fix it in this situation.

[image]

so i really want to fix in GLTF for AR. thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Are all the ice-cube things part of the same mesh in Blender, or are they separate objects?

Comment: not separate. same mesh!

Comment: Try making each one a separate object. Viewers may sort transparent objects.

Comment: wow.. thank you. it works well!!